# .on() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using .on() function of jquery to be able to do something when div content is changed.

Here's my code:

```
$( "div.contentdata" ).on( "onChange", function() {
      document.write(".on jquery function is working.");
      statement
      .
      .
      });
```

However it is not working.

This is the complete code

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/path/to/widget-scroller.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="static/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

    <script>    
       function loadTable(logtype) {
       var xmlhttp;         
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari             
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();         
       }        
       else
       {
       // code for IE6, IE5             
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");       
        }

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {          
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
               document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
       }

       if (logtype == "Option1") {
          xmlhttp.open("GET","/Option1",true); 
          }
       else if (logtype == "Option2"){
          xmlhttp.open("GET","/Option2",true);
          }

          xmlhttp.send();   
         } 

       </script> 


   <body> 
  <div id="alldiv">

        <!--Banner Div-->       <div id="bannertable">
                    BANNER


                            </div>

        <div id = "container" >         <table id="holder">             <tr id="tr1">
                    <td id ="td1">
                        <div id = "nav">
                            <a href="javascript:ddtreemenu.flatten('treemenu1', 'expand')">   Expand All</a> | <a href="javascript:ddtreemenu.flatten('treemenu1', 'contact')">Show All</a>
                            <ul id="treemenu1" class="treeview">
                                <li>System
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Monitoring</li>
                                    </ul>
                            >                                           <li><a href="#" onClick="loadTable('Option1')">Option1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" onClick="loadTable('Option2')">Option2</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                ddtreemenu.createTree("treemenu1", true)
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id = "td2">
                        <div id = "contents" class="contentdata">
                            tables
                        </div>
                    </td>           </tr>       </table>    </div> </div> 
</body> </html>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements don't have a `change` event. Under what circumstances do you expect the event to be triggered?

Comment: Why you are not using .ajax() function in jquery? why row method?

Comment: @BenM ohh okay. what can I use to instead of change?

Comment: try use on click? how can div be changed?

Comment: It depends. Under what circumstances do you expect the event to be triggered? @Phoenix jQuery isn't always the best method ;)

Comment: change `onChange` to `change`

Comment: When change of your div occur? You should call your div change logic after that.

Comment: @RahilWazir that won't help...

Comment: @ah-shianghan I meant the content of div. not the div itself. How do I do that?

Comment: Why not trigger what you want to do in the success function of AJAX?

Comment: Yes i know but OP bind the wrong event.

Comment: You could do `$("div.contentdata").trigger("onChange");` in your AJAX success.

Comment: @BenM I meant the content of div. I thought I could use change event for that. do you have any suggestions? recommendations?

Comment: @putvande where do I put the statements that I need to execute in this $("div.contentdata").trigger("onChange"); ?

Comment: @putvande he'd be better off using standard jQuery AJAX calls with `.done` callbacks than firing custom events.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm not saying it is the best way to do it. But it can be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, except `<div>` elements do not have a `change` event. If you need to triggere an event when the innterHTML of `div.contentdiv` is changed, you'd be better to do that in the `success` callback of your AJAX method (quite simple if you use jQuery's `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`).

You might also consider looking at [DOMNodeInserted](http://javascript.gakaa.com/domnodeinserted-description.aspx) and [DOMNodeRemoved](http://javascript.gakaa.com/domnoderemoved-description.aspx), but these are general mutation events and might not translate to your requirements.

Ben Nadel also blogged about a similar kind of issue [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1623-Ask-Ben-Detecting-When-DOM-Elements-Have-Been-Removed-With-jQuery.htm).

Comment: when you say success callback, where is it exactly? Inside this function after the statement? if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {               document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

Comment: Yes, exactly inside that function.

Answer (score 8):

1. standard event handlers registered with `.on` don't need an `"on"` prefix, and won't work if you include it.
2. Div's don't even fire a `change` event when their contents change anyway.
3. You can register for "DOMMutation" events that *do* fire when an element changes, but they're not widely supported, and are being replaced with an alternate API in the next version of the DOM specification.
4. Unless you're writing a browser extension, if your element's contents are changing, it will be *your* code that's doing it.   Figure out where (probably in your Ajax callback) and do your thang there instead.
5. You're using jQuery - use `$.get()` instead of rolling your own Ajax code with `XMLHttpRequest` objects.
6. You're still using jQuery - register *all* event handlers in your JS code, not "inline" with `"javascript:"` links.

Answer (score 0):

This should be changed!

```
$( "div.contentdata" ).on( "onChange", function() {
```

To this:

```
$( "div.contentdata" ).on( "Change", function() {
```

Second thing, please note divs don't have this method: `onchange` since their value is static and is not changed.

http://api.jquery.com/change/ (jQuery change)

This is used for `select`, `input` etc.

http://api.jquery.com/on/ (jQuery on)

jQuery Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

People use jQuery ajax nowadays, so please use it!

Comment: Even `contenteditable` `<div>` elements don't trigger the `change` event.

Comment: @Afzaal yes, the content of my div can be changed. As you can see in the complete code, Im using ajax call to import data from server. The content of the div depends on what the user clicks in my navigation tree.

Comment: No no, that is not what change actually is. Change means the value change, such as of input or select element. Div's value cannot change however its text or html can change! So you need to do that in `success` rather than in `change` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a custom eventHandler to do something, but you have to trigger it yourself.
You can trigger them by using `.trigger(...)`. Something like:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {          
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        // Trigger your custom eventHandler
        $("div.contentdata").trigger("onChange"); 
    }
}
```

The eventType you trigger with `trigger(...)` needs to be the same as you use with `.on(...)`

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/